# Почему в java конструкторы не наследуются?

Tags: java

Можно получить ответ простым человеческим языком?

Comment: В смысле не наследуются? Вопрос не понятен. Добавьте контекста

Comment: "Конструкторы не относятся к категории методов и не наследуются". Арнольд, Гослинг, Холмс.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вполне себе наследуются и вызываются из наследника с помощью ключевого слова `super()`

Не наследуются только приватные конструкторы и могут не наследоваться конструкторы с дефолтным доступом (если наследник в другом пакете)

Comment: Может не super(), а this(args)?

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать конструктор этого же класса, то да вы пишите this(), если же вам нужен конструктор родителя, то придется использовать super()